# How to send logs back to tkinter GUI from Robot framework?

Tags: python, tkinter, robotframework, python-multithreading

I have created GUI using python Tkinter. After clicking `run button` in the GUI, It will send  selected GUI variables (eg: text box values) to Robot framework. This is my design concept

```
Tkinter GUI ----> Run.bat ---> Execute Robot framework
```

**Run.bat**

```
@py -m robot -A robot.txt --variable myval:%arg1%  test_script.robot
```

This is working as expected. Now I want to scale my application such a way that, it will print the `logs` from Robot framework to Tkinter GUI `text area`.

I am planning to create a `Thread` in Tkinter to capture the real time logs from Robot framework.

**example:**

```
import os

*** Settings ***
Documentation  This test file


Suite Setup
Suite Teardown

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
Log To Console  \nargumrnt are => ${myval}

# if value is correct or not
IF  ${myval}
  send_back_to_Tkinter_GUI ("Value is OK") # Send back log to GUI from robot framework

ELSE
    send_back_to_Tkinter_GUI ("Value is Not OK") # Send back log to GUI from robot framework
    
END     

[Teardown]
```

I want to know, Is there any method available to get this logs from robot framework to tkinter?
or Any suggestion from your side to send back logs to Tkinter script?

Comment: Take a look at [subprocess](https://realpython.com/python-subprocess/) if the log is printed to stdout (the command line), if it's a file then just read it with `open`. And then update the text area every few ms (small tip: no need for threading just use the [`.after`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/) method)

Comment: https://github.com/rasjani/robotframework-guistatus -- Old archived project of mine, maybe you can get some ideas ? I have Tk Gui that also contains flask and then on robot side, from within Listener callbacks, i set the messages to the flask endpoint which then updates the UI ..